# Android | XML Button needs to reach the edges of left, right and bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I am trying to create a call button that is at bottom:0 and left and right are also 0dp. There is no padding between the button and the edge of the screen. That's what I want but my code does provide padding somewhere and I cannot find the problem.

Here's my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00aadd"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_red"
            android:onClick="buttonPhone_onClick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="@string/phone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me if you can, all help is appreciated.

If you need more info please let me know and I'll respond ASAP.

Thank you and have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have those paddings at your parent `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Remove them and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

By default `activity_horizontal_margin` and  `activity_vertical_margin` in `dimens.xml` is `16dp`
Refer your `dimens.xml` file:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```